# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Streams Binder KafkaException: Could not start stream: 'listener' cannot be null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I am new to Kafka Streams and Spring Cloud Stream but have read good things about it in terms of moving the integration related codes into properties file so devs can focus mostly on the business logic side of things.

Here I have my simple application class.

```
package com.some.events.consumer

import com.some.events.SomeEvent
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import java.util.function.Consumer

@SpringBootApplication
class ConsumerApplication {
    @Bean
    fun consume(): Consumer<KStream<String, SomeEvent>> {
        return Consumer { input -> input.foreach { key, value -> println("Key: $key, value: $value") } }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<ConsumerApplication>(*args)
}
```

My `application.yml` file is as follows.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: consume
    stream:
      bindings:
        consume-in-0:
          destination: "some-event"
          group: "some-event"
```

My dependencies in `build.gradle.kts` are defined as follows (just included the relevant ones here).

```
extra["springCloudVersion"] = "2020.0.2"

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${property("springCloudVersion")}")
    }
}
```

When I run the application I got the following exception.

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'streamsBuilderFactoryManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: ; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'listener' cannot be null
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at com.some.events.consumer.ConsumerApplicationKt.main(ConsumerApplication.kt:22) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: ; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'listener' cannot be null
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilderFactoryManager.start(StreamsBuilderFactoryManager.java:94) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'listener' cannot be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201) ~[spring-core-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.addListener(StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.java:268) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilderFactoryManager.start(StreamsBuilderFactoryManager.java:84) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    ... 15 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Note that I am aware that I need to configure the Serde and Avro related things (I am using Avro for event schema), but the thing is, the stream won't even run.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I tried googling this but no one has posted an issue where it's caused by 'listener' cannot be null. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug; it is fixed in the 3.1.3-SNAPSHOT

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/commit/f25dbff2b7fc0d0c742dd674a9e392057a34c86d

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/1030#issuecomment-804039087

I am not sure about the comment there; adding micrometer to the class path should resolve it.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I think the comment there says `Anyway, the test still fails after adding Micrometer, so I'm attaching the simple project, just unpack + run mvn test
kstream-component-beans-test.zip` so it doesn't resolve it by adding Micrometer, right? I might need to wait for the next release.

Comment: No; I meant that looking that the code, just adding Micrometer should be enough. I asked @sobychacko that question and his response: `>Oh, I think that comment was talking about the fact that the basic issue of the test failure remained (at the time) which we fixed in that commit along with the null check. He was stating that the null error went away after adding micrometer, but the test still failed due to other issues.`

Comment: Oh whooops. Got it. So adding this guy `io.micrometer:micrometer-core` to my dependencies should make it work?

Comment: I am not at my desk. You might also have to add a SimpleMeterRegistry @Bean.

Answer (score 1):

The `destination: "some-event"` should point to a kafka topic. Like `destination: "some-event-topic"`.

Then you have to create an interface for the listener `consume-in-0`. Using the spring annotations will make the project load this listener and it will not be null anymore.

```
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Input;

public interface KafkaListenerBinding {
    @Input("consume-in-0")
    KStream<String, String> inputStream();
}
```

Then you create a @Service to process messages from the listener `@StreamListener("consume-in-0")`.

```
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Log4j2
@Service
@EnableBinding(KafkaListenerBinding.class)
public class KafkaListenerService {

    @StreamListener("consume-in-0")
    public void process(KStream<String, String> input) {
        input.foreach((k,v) -> log.info(String.format("Key: %s, Value: %s",k,v)));
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Despite the bug said by @Gary Russel I am going to complete my answer with the functional manner to implement the Spring service.
The functional style can be achieved by defining the function at the `application.yml` file. There is an internal convention to use the name of the function and the posfix `in-0` and `out-0` for the bindings. You have to use this when defining the binding. More details [here](https://spring.io/blog/2020/07/20/introducing-java-functions-for-spring-cloud-stream-applications-part-1).

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: transformToUpperCase
      bindings:
        transformToUpperCase-in-0:
          destination: input-func-topic
        transformToUpperCase-out-0:
          destination: output-func-topic
```

Then you annotate your class with `@Configuration` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and make sure that the lambda method is the same that you defined on the `application.yml` file for the `function.definition`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class KafkaListenerFunctionalService {

    @Bean
    public Function<KStream<String, String>, KStream<String, String>> transformToUpperCase() {
        return input -> input
                .peek((k, v) -> log.info("Functional received Input: {}", v))
                .mapValues(i -> i.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use the functional programming style, i.e. `Function`, `Consumer`, etc. rather than the imperative style, e.g. `EnableBinding`, `StreamListener`, etc. Any thoughts?

Comment: I am also learning the functional style. For now I am good on the imperative style only. When I develop a hello-world example on this I complete this answer...

Comment: @billydh I added the functional example despite the bug that Gary said. I hope it helps...

Comment: nice well done on figuring out how to work around the bug. let me try this solution and will review your answer if it works.

Comment: actually i am confused here. you name the one in `KafkaListenerService` as `consume-in-0` but in your `application.yml` you don't list that. and then you define a different function which is `transformToUpperCase` and this is the one that's on `application.yml`. can you please enlighten me?

Comment: I assume that I am using your `application.yml` for the imperative way to use spring cloud stream. For the functional way the spring cloud stream recognizes the binding `transformToUpperCase-in-0` by the method `transformToUpperCase()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, so first i add the **io.micrometer** dependency(install the latest version from [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.micrometer/micrometer-core))

second create **Bean** from **SimpleMeterRegistry** and it solved the problem

```
@Bean
SimpleMeterRegistry simpleMeterRegistry() {
    return new SimpleMeterRegistry();
}
```