# Apache Kafka Streams Application with 2 functions not working

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I got 2 applications and 3 Kafka topics. The first application produces messages into the `pos-topic`. This application is working and the messages are written into the topic. In the other application (which is not working) i got 2 functions listening to that topic :

**hadoop:**

```
@Bean
fun hadoop(): Function<KStream<String, PosInvoice>, KStream<String, HadoopRecord>> {
    return Function { input: KStream<String, PosInvoice> ->
        input.mapValues { v -> recordBuilder.getMaskedInvoice(v) }
            .flatMapValues { v -> recordBuilder.getHadoopRecords(v) }
    }
}
```

**notification:**

```
@Bean
fun notification(): Function<KStream<String, PosInvoice>, KStream<String, Notification>> {
    return Function { input -> input.filter { _, v -> v.customerType.equals("PRIME", ignoreCase = true) }
        .mapValues { v -> recordBuilder.getNotification(v) }}
}
```

The hadoop-function schould produce to the `hadoop-sink-topic` and the notification-function should produce to the `notification-topic`. Both functions are within a `@Configuration` class.

The **main class** looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class JsonposfanoutApplication
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   runApplication<JsonposfanoutApplication>(*args)
}
```

And here is **the application.yml** :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        notification-in-0.destination: pos-topic
        notification-out-0.destination: loyalty-topic
        hadoop-in-0.destination: pos-topic
        hadoop-out-0.destination: hadoop-sink-topic
      function:
        definition: notification;hadoop
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            brokers: localhost:9092
            configuration:
              schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
          bindings:
            notification-out-0.producer.valueSerde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerde
            hadoop-out-0.producer.valueSerde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerde
```

The classes that are getting deserialized and serialized are Json-friendly. The first Application writes a Json-serialized value into the topic. So i do not need to explicit define my `consumer.value.serdes` and my `key.serdes` with Spring Cloud Streams right?

**Whats going wrong?**

I have no idea. I get no error or exception. The Application is just starting and finished after a few seconds. I have no info about my processors, so i think they do not even start.
All suspicious i got from Spring Boot is an Info:
`@Bean method FunctionConfiguration.po is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.`

**What did I try?**

I've tried alot in my application.yml but nothing helped and i reverted everything to the first version. Maybe i'm missing something elsewhere?

Comment: try `spring.cloud.function.definition` (no `stream`).

Comment: unfortunately nothing changed with that change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams` (version 3.1.2) to `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams:3.1.3-SNAPSHOT` solved my problem. For some reason i did not got this exception:
`org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'streamsBuilderFactoryManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: ; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'listener' cannot be null`
in my application but in another one.
Here is the answer that helped then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66888771/15359624

Answer (score 0):

I think for Kotlin applications, you need to define the `Configuration` class separately. The setup below works for me and I see both functions get activated.

```
@SpringBootApplication
class DemoKotlinApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoKotlinApplication>(*args)
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
class DemoKotlinConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun foo(): java.util.function.Function<KStream<String, String>, KStream<String, String>> {
        return Function { 
           input: KStream<String, String> -> input
        }
    }

    @Bean
    fun bar(): java.util.function.Function<KStream<String, String>, KStream<String, String>> {
        return Function { 
           input: KStream<String, String> -> input
        }
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=foo;bar
```

Comment: I actually have two Configuration classes for each function one. It also does not help to turn them into one.

Comment: Ok. Can you share a reproducible small sample app that is self-contained, where we can see the problem?

Comment: Thank you for letting me write a sample app! In the sample App i had the following exceptopn: `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'streamsBuilderFactoryManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: ; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'listener' cannot be null`
So i used `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams:3.1.3-SNAPSHOT` instead of version 3.1.2 and everything worked. The same change also solved the problem in the other application.